# Mysql further join using concatenated field on a union result to filter them

Tags: mysql

I have two tables containing three columns containing the same types of information(id, attributes, and amounts). I would like to combine them in a union and join that union with another table containing a list of id's to filter them, then sum common attributes.

```
table_a                     table_b                   table_ids
id   attr    amount         id   attr     amount      uid     a_id
1    'atr1'  10             1    'atr2'   4           'id1'   1
1    'atr2'  5              2    'atr3'   2           'id2'   2
2    'atr3'  7              2    'atr1'   11
3    'atr1'  8
```

I tried

```
SELECT table_ids.uid, t.attr, SUM(t.amount)
FROM table_ids
JOIN (SELECT CONCAT('a', id) AS comb_id, attr, amount FROM table_a
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CONCAT('b', id) AS comb_id, attr, amount FROM table_b
    ) t
ON CONCAT('a', table_ids.a_id) = t.comb_id
GROUP BY t.attr
```

but am only getting the attribute for last matching a_id and the number of matching rows times the last matching row amount for the sum.

(There will be another table with more id's filtering table_b attributes but I haven't even gotten one filtering table to work yet.)

Comment: It feels as though you are doing this in an ill advised manner, why not just use the numerics without CONCAT, as the CONCAT will slow this down massively.  Will type up an example - depends a lot on where the table_b ids will join to though tbh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to be 100% sure what you are aiming for but something like this may fit the bill

```
SELECT
    joinedData.uid,
    joinedData.attr,
    SUM(joinedData.amount) AS amount
FROM (
    (
        SELECT
            table_ids.uid,
            table_a.attr,
            SUM(table_a.amount) AS amount
        FROM table_a
        INNER JOIN table_ids
        ON table_ids.a_id = table_a.id
        GROUP BY table_ids.uid, table_a.attr
    )
    UNION
    (
        SELECT
            table_ids.uid,
            table_b.attr,
            SUM(table_b.amount) AS amount
        FROM table_b
        INNER JOIN table_ids
        ON table_ids.b_id = table_b.id
        GROUP BY table_ids.uid, table_b.attr
    )
) AS joinedData
GROUP BY joinedData.uid, joinedData.attr
```

Have of course assumed that table_b will join id onto table_ids.b_id, change it as required.